# How to use tls.Config GetClientCertificate()

Tags: go, tls1.2

I'm using the Go http client to do mutual tls verify for different endpoints(or different client cert for different servers).

Not sure if GetClientCertificate() could be used for it. I'm a little confused about it. Because CertificateRequestInfo doesn't have server endpoint or host info.

- crypto/tls

```golang
    GetClientCertificate func(*CertificateRequestInfo) (*Certificate, error) // Go 1.8
```

- source code
  https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/common.go#L526

It would be great if someone could give such an example? or maybe any other method to meet this requirement?

```sh
go version go1.13.3 linux/amd64
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@sirsean/mutually-authenticated-tls-from-a-go-client-92a117e605a1, 
https://gist.github.com/michaljemala/d6f4e01c4834bf47a9c4

Comment: The reason `CertificateRequestInfo` doesn't have the server name is that you had to specify it in the http request, so you should already know it.

Comment: hi @marc thanks for your reply.
Just doing mutual Authenticated TLS for 1 server, it's simple. But here the requirement is that there are multiple servers and there client could have multiple certificates.

Maybe it'd better register the client certificate and create the connection at the request level. Of course, another option is to create an HTTP client for each host.

Comment: I would create one `http.Client` per server to talk to (or at least, one client per client certificate).

Answer (score 0):

One approach, from @marc, is to create one `http.Client` per server to talk to (or at least, one client per client certificate).

But the limitation is that it's hard to set params for `http.Transport`, like `MaxIdleConns`. Another limitation is to dynamically update or use new certificates.

By digging into the Golang-1.14.5 source code, maybe `http.Transport.DialTLSContext` could meet the requirement, which could create TLS connection(cert is from context) at request-level. Does anyone have any idea or comments for this approach? One drawback is that it's a little complicated to customize a DialTLSContext() functions, because the underlying functions are implemented well for it.